# PDF annotation tool for Mac OS

Tags: pdf

What is the Mac OS application that provides most similar function as PDF annotator in Windows?

I just want a program that enables simple annotating functions in Mac OS. 
Of course, freeware is preferred.

Add:
Thank you for recommending Preview. 
But I need a little more advanced features than Preview.
Any recommendation?

Comment: What specific features do you need?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Preview to annotate PDFs, make circles, arrows, texts, and even sign it.

It comes with OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Preview (which comes with OS X) will do simple annotations.

In the toolbar, look for the edit icon: [image: edit icon]

Click on this icon, and you'll see a new toolbar appear which lets you create squares, circles, speech bubbles, text notes, sticky notes, and more.

[image: Toolbar]

Then you can save the file as normal.